# In android, how to read control value from a fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe

I am new to android development, so bear with me, I need to show record with lots of field from database on the screen for update, I chose to use horizontal swipe with tabs to accommodate the large amount of field with viewpager and fragmentpageadaptor (if there is a better way to do this, please enlighten me). My question what I should do to read and set values from controls in fragments, I could not find a way to refer to them, thanks,

Comment: Where do you need to refer to them from? Your activity?

Comment: Yes, in the main activity, I want to write values into controls in different fragment, and also read them back (some changed by user).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method on the fragment that would accept all the information you need to populate the controls. You can wrap all the information in a single class of you would have many parameters in the method.

You can then call this method from your activity and populate the controls this way.